# BlankToken Transaction

Tags: remix, kovan

So i deployed my smart contract on Kovan Network using Remix IDE, i after successful compilation I added the arguments of the constructor to create the token, it deployed successfully but the issue now is the token I created did not appear on etherscan even though I can see contract name and transaction hash.

However, I can interact with the functions on Remix IDE as you can see on the screenshot
[image]

[image]

Here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/QWj1NgBA) to the smart contract code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QWj1NgBA)

Also see the deployed smart contract on [etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x912da13e52ee95e9ebaa345e5323ccea6915d521) [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x912da13e52ee95e9ebaa345e5323ccea6915d521)

Comment: Etherscan is a closed source third party block explorer so it is better to ask them directly. Testnets like kovan or rinkeby are not updated immediately, without some operation it can't identify a contract as token. A few things you might try: 1/ send a successful token transfer, 2/ register source code, 3/ wait.

Comment: Ok, let me try and revert back. Thank you for taking the time.